# Call array out of loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

How do i print my array from outside my code.

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor(){
    let buttonNamesAndColor = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10]

    var counter = 0

    for i in 0...9 {
        var val = NamePicker()
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.setTitle(val, for: .normal)
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.sizeToFit()

        // array to find duplicates
        var buttonValues = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] // array for button names
        buttonValues.insert(val, at: counter)
        counter += 1
        print(buttonValues[counter])
    }
}
```

My code is give names to my buttons inside of my buttonNamesAndColor array, when each one is given an array it is inserted into my buttonValues array. I would like to see that array printed out outside of the function.

I would like to print out the whole array just to see that 1. I can call it outside of the function and 2. to see it store all the correct values.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. If you have an instance method of a class that populates an array and saves the array as a property of the object, it's easy. If your function example is creating an array in a local variable then that array ceases to exist as soon as you return from the function. You need to show the array, how it's defined, and how your example function creates it.

Comment: you need to declare your array as a property of your class, move the declaration out of buttonNameSetAndColor method

Answer (score 0):

As you currently have it, you cannot access the `buttonNamesAndColor` array from outside the `buttonNameSetAndColor` function. At the end of the `buttonNameSetAndColor` function, that array is no longer in scope.

All of the options below will allow you to access and print the array outside of the `buttonNameSetAndColor` function.

I'm assuming that your `button1, button2, etc.` are `UIButton`'s, but the following would work if they are of another type.

**Option 1:** Create an instance property on your class/struct for the array. There other variations that could be used here, it will depend on your needs.

```
class SomeClass {
    private var buttonNamesAndColor: [UIButton]

    // or

    private var _buttonNamesAndColor = [UIButton]()
    var buttonNamesAndColor: [UIButton] {
        return _buttonNamesAndColor
    }

    // or

    var buttonNamesAndColor: [UIButton]

    ...
}
```

**Option 2:** Return an array from the `buttonNameSetAndColor` function.

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor() -> [UIButton] {
    ...
}
```

**Option 3:** If your `button` instances are value types. Pass the array in as a `inout` parameter. Any mutations of the array passed to this function will persist beyond the scope of the function.

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor(_ array: inout [Button]) {
    ...
}
```

This option would be called with something like:

```
var buttonNamesAndColor = [button1, button2, button3] // Note "var" instead of "let"
buttonNamesSetAndColor(&buttonNamesAndColor) // Note "&" symbol
```

**Option 4:** If the `button` instances are reference types, then you can just pass the array into your `buttonNameSetAndColor` function without the `inout`.

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor(_ array: [UIButton]) {
    ...
}
```

This would be used like this:

```
var buttonNamesAndColor = [button1, button2, button3] // Note "var" instead of "let"
buttonNamesSetAndColor(buttonNamesAndColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor(){

    let buttonNamesAndColor = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10]

    var counter = 0
    var buttonValues = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""] // array for button names

    for i in 0...9 {
        var val = NamePicker()
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.setTitle(val, for: .normal)
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.sizeToFit()

        // array to find duplicates
        buttonValues.insert(val, at: counter)
        counter += 1
        print(buttonValues[counter])
    }
}
```